# Безопасность twig

Tags: безопасность, twig

Использую twig как шаблонизатор. Появилась необходимость дать пользователям (сотрудники. очень небольшое число) делать свои шаблоны (простенькие) для вставки данных (я сам определяю набор данных). После рендеринга текст уходит в БД (текст экранирован). Насколько безопасно давать пользователям создавать свои шаблоны?

Comment: В бд можно записывать все что угодно, главное то, что вы делаете потом с результатом. Если пользователи засунули в шаблон скрипт (предположим), а вы потом как админ просмотрели страницу с выполнением стороннего скрипта, то может что-то и произойти при условии наличия уязвимостей на сайте.

Comment: @Visman, т.е. опасаться стоит только этого? К моему счастью сотрудникам запрещено  в текст вставлять теги (все теги удаляются).